# How to display image from a RSS feed

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to build an app that shows the latest RSS feeds from http://news.yahoo.com/rss/
I'm able to parse the xml using NSXMLParserDelegate, I'm able to show the date and time along with the title for the particular feed, but I also want to display an image for every feed, I know how to parse the main elements but I dont know how to pass the attributes for a child element which has a url as its key... e.g. the above feed consists of the following:

```
<item>
  <title>fooo</title>
  <description ahref="some link" image src="http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Wo3_apH.kz7DMvOj7MDtRQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/20c464ff99815420210f6a706700a792.jpg"
     </description>
```

I need the image from the IMG SRC in my tableview along with the title and date for that particular feed. I'm confused as to how to parse the IMG SRC attribute and add it to my tableview with altered size so that it doesnt disrupt my title and date.

What I have done so far:

#### viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     if ([stories count] == 0) 
     {
         NSString * path = @"http://news.yahoo.com/rss/";
         [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
     }
     cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 80);
 }
```

#### -(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL

```
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [rssParser parse];
}
```

#### didStartElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
```

#### foundCharacters

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    }
}
```

#### didEndElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
    }
}
```

#### didEndDocument

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    [newsTable reloadData];
}
```

#### numberOfRows and cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [stories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"pubDate"];

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    return cell;
}
```

How do I get the image on the right hand side of the cell?

Comment: ` <item>
     <title>fooo</title>
     <description ahref="some link" image src="http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Wo3_apH.kz7DMvOj7MDtRQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/20c464ff99815420210f6a706700a792.jpg"
        </description>`

Comment: http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Wo3_apH.kz7DMvOj7MDtRQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/20c464ff99815420210f6a706700a792.jpg

Comment: here you will have to parse the link and meta data ....download the image from link ,according to me the most efficient way will be to make an object class to store the values you have to display on tableview cell store it in a mutable array which includes the image also you will be downloading.

Comment: That sample feed cannot be right. You're missing a ">", and the `image` portion looks completely wrong. Please confirm.

Comment: try this http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Wo3_apH.kz7DMvOj7MDtRQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/20c464ff99815420210f6a706700a792.jpg

Comment: i have taken out some of the unreadable stuff just to make it readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the question in the title, to load an image, you parse the RSS feed for the URL of the string using `NSXMLParser` object, and when you want to present that image to the user, you use that URL to retrieve the image into a `NSData`, create a `UIImage` for that, and then set the `image` property of the `UIImageView` accordingly. See the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the listing below.

In terms of the specifics of the implementation, I've significantly revised this answer on the basis of the fact that you're reading a feed from http://news.yahoo.com/rss/ which has a format significantly different than what you show in your example XML listing. The format actually appears to be:

```xml
<item>
  <title>Palestinian death toll ...</title>
  <description>this contains the html version of the story description</description>
  <link>http://news.yahoo.com/palestinian-death-toll-...</link>
  <pubDate>Mon, 19 Nov 2012 11:20:15 -0500</pubDate>
  <source url="http://www.reuters.com/">Reuters</source>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">palestinian-death-toll-...</guid>
  <media:content url="http://the.url.for.image/images/palestinian.JPG" type="image/jpeg" width="130" height="86"></media:content>
  <media:text type="html">another html version of the text</media:text>
  <media:credit role="publishing company"></media:credit>
</item>
```

Some of this is just standard XML tags `title`, `description`, etc. where you're grabbing values between the open and close tags (for which you can just use `NSXMLParserDelegate` method `parser:foundCharacters:`). But the image URL is actually inside the `url` attribute of the `media:content` tag, itself, in which case you have to use the `NSXMLParserDelegate` method `didStartElement` and inquire on the `attributes` parameter.

So, given that, I've uploaded a [sample Yahoo News reader](https://github.com/robertmryan/Simple-XML-Parser) which demonstrates the process of parsing the Yahoo RSS feed. Note, this is a fairly primitive implementation, but hopefully this gives you the basic idea.

Comment: i understand the code you have provided me above,but i am seriously confused as to how to retrieve a child element attribute and after retrieving all the url's in an array where should i use the above code? apart from the NSXMLParser can you suggest me any other easy parser? thanks

Comment: the above code is really cool thanks..but i didnt understand the last line self.imageView.image = image; i want to show the images for every feed

Comment: i did the following http://pastie.org/5402327 but i am having an NSArray and NSString conflict and besides that my NSLog doesnt show me anything in my array :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19774/discussion-between-rob-and-boredtodeath)